# Find a control to display a hyperlink on a text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string: "ABC BCC CDD". When I set this text to control, control will display ABC, BCC, CDD like a hyperlink. I need this control. Thanks.

My application is C# WinForm, .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, maybe I undetstand your question incorrectly, but...
Here listed all most used Window Form controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511482.aspx

How about the LinkLabel, is it what you're looking for? Read more about the LinkLabel class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx

Sorry if I missed...

Comment: No, it only display hyperlink on words, example: "ABC", "BCC", "CDD". The space between words will not display like a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think just check there property and it will ask for which page you want to navigate this is simple way for making the text a hyperlink. and ofcourse it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For an Hyperlink effect in WinForms, use [`LinkLabel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/897fcdkf.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

May be [LinkLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) control?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement your own UserControl with the help of LinkLabel (ie. splitting the text to an array of words and use each one in a LinkLabel). Of course this is one way to do it. There's many ways to do it but I don't think there's an easy one.